# How do I set focus on one Input instead of all in a React component?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to focus the parent when an `input` gets focused using state. However when an input is focused, all the other inputs are also getting focused too. I am not sure what to do to achieve this, your assistance will be much appreciated.

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFocused: false,
    };
  }

  onFocus = () => {
    this.setState({
      isFocused: true,
    });
  };

  onBlur = () => {
    this.setState({
      isFocused: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <StyledFormItem focused={this.state.isFocused === true}>
            <StyledInput
              onFocus={this.onFocus}
              onBlur={this.onBlur}
              size="large"
              addonAfter={<Mail size={18} />}
              placeholder="Email Address"
            />
        </StyledFormItem>

        <StyledFormItem focused={this.state.isFocused === true}>
            <StyledInput
              onFocus={this.onFocus}
              onBlur={this.onBlur}
              size="large"
              addonAfter={<Lock size={18} />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
        </StyledFormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that problem because both of your `StyledFormItem` are referring to the same value `state.isFocused`.

A quick solution is to switch from a single value in your state `isFocused` to an key-pair object for each of your input `focus` value and use the input `name` to keep track of which value should be updated inside the event handler. You can change your component to something like:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      focuses: {
         email: false,
         password: false
      },
    };
  }

  onFocus = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      focuses: {...this.state.focuses, [evt.target.name]: true},
    });
  };

  onBlur = () => {
    this.setState({
      focuses: {...this.state.focuses, [evt.target.name]: false},
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <StyledFormItem focused={this.state.focuses.email}>
            <StyledInput
              onFocus={this.onFocus}
              onBlur={this.onBlur}
              size="large"
              name="email"
              addonAfter={<Mail size={18} />}
              placeholder="Email Address"
            />
        </StyledFormItem>

        <StyledFormItem focused={this.state.focuses.password}>
            <StyledInput
              onFocus={this.onFocus}
              onBlur={this.onBlur}
              size="large"
              name="password"
              addonAfter={<Lock size={18} />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
        </StyledFormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Another, more encapsulated and componentizing solution will be convert  and  to a single component, then have an internal state inside to control the focus value.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I've been trying to use `refs`, should've looked somewhere else. But not sure is more ideal tho.

Comment: You don't really need to use `ref` for this situation, however, if you still want to explore it, the idea is to obtain the ref of `StyledFormItem` and use it inside the `StyledInput` event handler to trigger `focus`.